# Setting custom cell uibutton titles from an array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

I'm working with uitableview custom cell.
To output information in it i've added one `UILabel` and two `UIButtons`.
For the data structure i've created a custom class

```
class Question {
    var ask: String
    var answers: [String]

    var nextQuestions = [Question?]()

    init(question: String, ans: [String]) {
        self.ask = question
        self.answers = ans
    }
```

Here is my `ViewController` function code for adding the data

```
func setupQuestion() {

let q1 = Question(question: "What is your favourite breakfast", ans: ["Pancakes", "Waffles"])
let q2 = Question(question: "What do you have for dinner", ans: ["Steak", "Spaghetti"])

nextQuestions.append(q1)
nextQuestions.append(q2)
}
```

Here is how i output the data via the `setCell` function

```
func setCell(Question: String, optionone: [String], optiontwo: [String])
{
    self.mainText.text = Question
    self.optionOne.setTitle(optionone, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    self.optionTwo.setTitle(optiontwo, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Here is the implementation of the `setCell` in `ViewController` (in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)

```
    let quest = nextQuestions[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(quest.question, optionone: quest.ans, optiontwo: quest.ans)
```

My issue is - because i have the `uibutton` titles are set in an array `optionone: [String], optiontwo: [String]` how do i properly output them in the `setCell` function and its implementation in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of objects of type `Question` and a custom cell that shows information about a question. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just fetch one question and pass it as argument in custom cell `setCell` function.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let question = nextQuestions[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(question)
    return cell
}
```

In `setCell` function fill UI with your data

```
func setCell(question: Question)
{
    self.mainText.text = question.ask
    self.optionOne.setTitle(question.answers[0], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    self.optionTwo.setTitle(optiontwo.answers[1], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
}
```